# Why there are so many array of weights?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am working on python with keras.  I learned in my theory study that in a neural network the weights are only between the input layer and a hidden layer or between hidden layers.
I wrote this code, where I added two layers:

```
NN.add(Dense(4, input_shape=array_input.shape, activation='relu', name="Layer", kernel_constraint=changeWeight()))
NN.add(Dense(4, activation='relu', name="Output"))
NN.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.3), metrics=['accuracy'])
print(NN.summary())
a = NN.fit(array_input, array_input, epochs=100)
for lay in NN.layers:
    print(lay.name)
    print(lay.get_weights())
```

I think that one is the hidden layer (the one renamed "Layer") and the other is the output layer. The problem is that if i printed "lay.get_weights()" there are two arrays of weights, one for each layer. Like this:

```
[array([[-1.5516974 , -1.600516  , -0.        ,  0.        ],
       [-0.        , -2.1766946 ,  0.32734624, -0.        ],
       [-0.        , -0.        ,  0.32156652, -0.812184  ],
       [-0.        , -0.        , -0.        , -0.7288372 ]],
      dtype=float32), array([-1.8015273, -1.801546 , -0.1462403,  0.       ], dtype=float32)]
Output
[array([[-1.5045888 , -0.14155084, -0.29977936, -0.0492779 ],
       [-1.2379107 , -0.44411597, -0.41499865, -0.2560569 ],
       [ 1.2397875 , -0.3541401 ,  1.2223543 ,  1.5617256 ],
       [ 0.18388063,  0.44298917, -0.2201969 , -0.1165269 ]],
      dtype=float32), array([-0.82720596,  0.        ,  1.1942271 ,  1.7084894 ], dtype=float32)]
```

Can someone explain to me where is the problem. I don't understand keras API, do I?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer#get_weights
get_weights() returns the weight and value of the bias in an array.

Each of your inputs is connected to the first layers. So the weight matrix has a shape of (input.shape, number of neurons in the current layer) and the bias vector has a shape of (number of neurons in the current layer, ).
Therefore, without knowing what your input array contains, I know that this array has a shape of (4,).

For the second layer, the same process is repeated

- weight : (number of neurons of the last layer, number of neurons of the current layer)
- bias (number of neurone of the current layer,)

Try this example:

```
NN = Sequential()
NN.add(Dense(2, input_shape=(3,), activation='relu', name="Layer"))
NN.add(Dense(4, activation='relu', name="Output"))

for lay in NN.layers:
    print(lay.name)
    print(lay.get_weights())
```

Output:

```
Layer
[array([[-0.674668  , -0.34347552],
       [ 0.63090587,  0.8558588 ],
       [-0.5063792 , -0.23311883]], dtype=float32), array([0., 0.], dtype=float32)]
Output
[array([[-0.07787323,  0.22444701,  0.52729607,  0.07616615],
       [-0.5380094 , -0.3146367 , -0.73177123, -0.9248886 ]],
      dtype=float32), array([0., 0., 0., 0.], dtype=float32)]
```

Graphical representation :

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Now I am understanding more than before, but I don't know why the second layer has an array of weight. In my mind this neural network has three layer, one of input, one of hidden nodes and one of output. So there should be only one array of weights. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, there are 3 layers here: The input, the hidden layer named "Layer" and the "Output" layer. There are weights and bias between the input layer and "Layers" and another set of weights and bias between "Layer" and "Output".

Comment: But the Layer that i renamed "Output" is the Output layer, isn't it? Because I don't understand why there are weights in the last layer. In the theory all books say that the weights are only between hidden layers or bewteen input layer and hidden layer. Is this wrong?

Comment: There are weights and bias between each layer, look at the graph I added. If you have a model without hidden layers, there will only be a set of weights and bias between the input and the output.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I understand more about the weights.